# ошибка при использовании -D для спрингового приложения

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Приложение на tomcat+spring
Запускаю из идеи на локальном томкате и, в шаге с мавен, выполняю команду

`package -Dgroups="data.UnitTest"`

для сбоки war-файла с прогоном UT без IT- все ок.

Мне требуется передать в приложение парамметр myEnv, чтобы прочитать из WEbInitializer, но, при попытке выполнить

`package -Dgroups="unit.ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.UnitTest" -DmyEnv="at1"`

(даже пока не читая его на стороне приложения - ошибка деплоя артефакта)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы передаете параметры в момент сборки приложения, а нужно передавать в момент запуска

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать. Передавать параметры в build artifact как-то тоже мне кажется странным

Comment: вообще это не особо хорошо, передавать параметры таким образом, для таких целей используют consul или что то подобное. Если очень хочется то  в wildfly или tomcat  (не знаю куда вы деплоите свой war) есть возможность задать параметры (например так https://crunchify.com/how-to-change-jvm-heap-setting-xms-xmx-of-tomcat/)

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov деплой на локальный томкат и на удаленный сервер тоже с томкатом, в перспективе еще was.

Answer (score 0):

1. Указать параметр VMOptions

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. добавить в ресурсы application.properties и его варианты application-dev.properties и т.д.
3. Исправить на

   @PropertySource("classpath:application-${myEnv}.properties")